# Include latex macros in eps/pdf images

Tags: macros, eps

Is it possible to have latex macros in eps (or some other format) images instead of using fixed text? I want to be able to change some variable names that are also used in figures.

Comment: have a look at `psfrag`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the info I guess this is almost what I need. But as it turns out, Inkscape exported images are not compatible with psfrag. Anyway, if you make the comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Does Inkscape have the capability to export text as TeX though?

Comment: @Werner it can export tex, but still vectorizes the text for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `psfrag` if the text of the eps file is stored in a manner, so that `psfrag` can work with it.

On my Ubuntu machine I use the program Dia to draw simple vector graphics. If I export the drawing using the GUI, it does not work. With the command line I can pass an option that does the trick.

`dia -t eps-builtin -e file.eps file.dia`

That may not answer your question exactly, but check out the export settings of inkscape. Maybe you can make it work.